# vuex modules test con jest

Tags: vue.js, vuex, test, jest

Estoy intentando testear un modulo de Vuex que tiene los metodos para registrar usuarios y login usando firebase pero he probado muchisimos ejemplos y siempre obtengo el mismo error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined.
La estructura de mi proyecto es la siguiente. Dentro de la carpeta Store tengo un archivo index.js con el siguiente codigo

```
   import Vue from 'vue'
   import Vuex from 'vuex'
   import { auth } from './auth.module';

   Vue.use(Vuex)

   export default new Vuex.Store({
     modules: {
        auth
      }
   })
```

y la definicion de mi modulo en el archivo auth.module.js como sigue

```
   import AuthService from '../services/auth.service';
   import router from '@/router/index'
   import firebase from 'firebase/app'
   import 'firebase/auth'


export const auth = {

namespaced: true,
state: {
    user: null,
    error: null,
    status: null,
    emailSent: false,
    isLogged: false,
    loading: false
},
mutations: {
    setUser(state, user) {
        state.user = user;
    },
    removeUser(state){
        state.user = null;
    },
    setError(state, error){
        state.error = error;
    },
    setEmailSent(state, value){
        state.emailSent = value;
    },
    setLoading(state, value) {
        state.loading = value;
    },
    setIsLogged(state, value) {
        state.isLogged = value;
    },
    setStatus(state, value) {
        state.status = value;
    }
},
actions: {
    async loginWithFirebase({ commit, state }, user) {

        const promises = [];

        const setPersistence = await AuthService.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)

        commit('setLoading', true);

        const login = await AuthService.login(user)
            .then((response) => {
                if(!response.user.emailVerified){
                    throw "Correo electrónico no verificado";
                } else {
                    commit('setIsLogged', true);
                    commit('setError', null);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                commit('setError', error);
            })
        

        promises.push(setPersistence);
        promises.push(login);

        Promise.all(promises)
            .then(() => {
                if (state.isLogged === true) {
                    commit('setLoading', false);
                    router.replace('dashboard');
                }     
            })
                       
    },

    async signUpAction({commit}, user){
        commit('setLoading', true);
        await AuthService.signUp(user)
            .then((response) => {
                user.id = response.user.uid;
                commit('setLoading', false);
                commit('setError', null);
               
                this.dispatch('auth/saveUserDB', user);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                commit('setLoading', false);
                commit('setError', error);
            })
          
    },

    async saveUserDB({ commit }, user) { 
        try {
            await AuthService.saveUser(user)
                .then(() => {
                    commit('setError', null)
                    commit('setEmailSent', true)
                    commit('setLoading', false)  
                })
          } catch(error){
              console.error('ha ocurrido un error: ', error.message)
              this.dispatch('auth/removeUserAccount')
          }
    },

    async removeUserAccount() {
        await AuthService.removeUserAccount();
    },

    async getUser({ commit }, uid){  
        await AuthService.getUser(uid)
          .then((doc) => {  
            commit('setUser', doc.data());
          })
          .catch((err) =>{
            console.error(err.code);
          })
    },

    async  signOutAction({commit}){
        firebase.auth().signOut()
        .then(()=>{
          router.replace({name: 'home'})
          commit('setIsLogged', false);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          commit('setError', error.message);
        })
      },

    async  resetPassword({commit}, email){
        commit('setLoading', true)
        await AuthService.resetPassword(email)
            .then(function() {
                commit('setStatus', 'success');
                commit('setError', null);
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                commit('setLoading', false)
                commit('setStatus', 'failure');
                commit('setError', error);
            })
    }
    
}
```

}

Probe varios test pero siempre obtengo un error que me muestra la parte del codigo del index donde exporta el store

aqui un ejemplo de test

```
import {shallowMount , createLocalVue} from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import authModule from '@/store/auth.module'


describe('authModule', () => {
   const localVue = createLocalVue();
   localVue.use(Vuex)

   beforeEach(() => {
       store = new Vuex.Store({
           modules: {
              auth: authModule,
          }
       })
    });

   it('set state.user when commit setUser', () =>{

        console.log('running test')
       })
  })
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que el test no tiene mucho sentido pero no importa que codigo escriba siempre obtengo el mismo error. Entiendo que es algo al importar el store pero no entiendo que es lo que puede estar funcionando mal

Answer (score 0):

Después de mucho probar encontré que el problema estaba en que mi módulo importa firebase y un services y no estaba creando mocks para eso. Por si a alguno le pasa. Empecé por crear las mutaciones en un fichero aparte y testear eso solo